# Login with Apple ID

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to integrate "**Login with Apple Id**" same as (Login with Facebook or Twitter). so is there any Api that gives me Apple ID. or is it possible or not? . 
Thank You.

Comment: There might me. But I afraid that apple may reject it..!!!

Comment: yup thats y m asking. :) . so is it possible or not?

Comment: Im not sure its documented for public. But many private websites like appannie, appfigures are login with our itunesconnect account so there is an illegal way for sure.

Comment: ok buddy . let me check. thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this is not possible (the legal way I think). This is not a social networking site we are talking about, So I do not think Apple would allow this.
It would be better if you asked your question here :- [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/index.jspa)

Hope you get some help from there :)....